# GUI for configure -> make -> make install

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, gui

I found a KDE gui for the configure -> make -> make install routine, [kconfigure](http://kconfigure.sourceforge.net). But, I did not try it out, since the project was last active in 2005. Is there a gui for the same for Ubuntu. I know that typing out a few lines is not a hassle, but having the option to use a gui instead wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [ubucompilator](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/) ( [Download Link](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/downloads/detail?name=ubucompilator_0.99.1-1_all.deb&can=2&q=) )

[image]

> Ubucompilator is a gui to compile and make .deb by the source code.
>
> An easy software to ubuntu, debian, linux mint to compile, make, install and create a .deb package.

## [DebianPackageMaker](http://code.google.com/p/debianpackagemaker/) ([Download Link](http://code.google.com/p/debianpackagemaker/downloads/detail?name=dpm_0.4.1%7Ewelemski1_i386.deb&can=2&q=))

[image]

> DebianPackageMaker is a simple user interface/tool to make a debian package easier and straightforward to use and deploy your linux application to any debian based distro.

Comment: does it take care of dependencies?

Comment: @abel i don't think so but neither does configure-> make -> make install .

Comment: I was waiting for some more. But..