# how do I get the Hanvon graphic tablet driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet

I have a [Hanvon Graphic Tablet](http://www.hanvon.com/en/products/tablets/index.html), and guides are suggesting I should compile the driver.

I have never had to compile a program before. A link to the driver is in this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1151464&page=2).

I love Ubuntu and this tablet is the only reason I use Windows. I am disabled with nothing to do. I need to doodle, it is what I love to do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That forum post is pretty old...looks like it was intended for Ubuntu 9.04. What version of Ubuntu are you using now?

Comment: 11.10 I just got the Tablet  in sept, and I just foung the driver not to long ago.

Comment: I am on 11.10 run Unity with a few ppa's classic men on my computer.  My computer didn't support gnome 3.

Comment: Hi Jason, I just found your other post [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1831164&page=3) which points at [this page](http://linux.fjfi.cvut.cz/~taxman/hw/hanvon/), is that where you are stuck now? If yes, you should look at [this Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42994/gui-for-configure-make-make-install) question for an easier way forward. Can you try it and see? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not compile drivers, you will loose either security updates or your new driver when you get security updates.

Instead all drivers should be installed using a dkms package, these are special packages which will be automatically compiled for you when a new kernel version is installed.

I noticed that there was no dkms package for the hanvon driver, so I made one for you and uploaded it to my ppa here:

https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/wacom-plus

You can add the ppa for precise using the instructions on that page, once you have it run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hanvon-dkms
```

This will install the driver as supplied from http://forschung.wi.uni-passau.de/~ond/hw/hanvon/ with no extra configuration. it will keep the driver installed not mater how many updates.

Please let me know if this works and how well it works since I don't have a hanvon tablet to test it. I suspect the tablet will only work if it's plugged in when you start ubuntu and won't plug-and-play, please test this and let me know.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm getting 404's on your ppa. I do have a hanvon tablet, but I am unfamiliar with creating my own PPA's and packages. I am able to compile the drivers however, and this is working as a temporary solution.