# How to compile software in Ubuntu without ever using the command line

Tags: compiling

Every time you want to build a software from source, you need to enter a lot of commands in the terminal. Is there a way to compile software using a graphical user interface?

Comment: Maybe using an IDE. The terminal is better, though, you learn more from it and have more control. You should put more details about your problem in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via [GUI for configure -> make -> make install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42994/gui-for-configure-make-make-install),

## [ubucompilator](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/) ( [Download Link](http://code.google.com/p/ubucompilator/downloads/detail?name=ubucompilator_0.99.1-1_all.deb&can=2&q=) )

[image]

> Ubucompilator is a gui to compile and make .deb by the source code.
>
> An easy software to ubuntu, debian, linux mint to compile, make, install and create a .deb package.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04 I have to manually download the dependencies ( googled each one ) ...and they are 11 ...so if you are going to use it on Ubuntu 13.04 .... its take time......

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu 13.04 amd 64 dependencies , download it and extract it and install it .. http://ubuntuone.com/1Dhoh4PfUd4syZnLH4NcOj

Answer (score 1):

You can do a shell script where you write all your commands and then you execute the script each time you want to use them :

The script (in a file called "*myscript.sh*") :

```
#!/bin/bash

Write your commands here
```

And then in the terminal :

```
The Terminal :-$ chmod +x myscript.sh    # Doing it once to have the right to execute it
The Terminal :-$ ./myscript.sh           # Each time you want to run your commands
```

Have also a look at ***software automation tools*** like GNU **make** (with its famous "*makefiles*").

There are plenty of tutorials and examples on the Web which shows you how to write a shell script ("BASH scripts") or makefiles.

NB : it is not specific to Ubuntu or Linux.